# I keep getting an error for my predicted values

Tags: r, regression

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

```
Regression_Africa <- Mean_temperature_by_dt %>%
  filter(Country == "Africa", dt >= 1850 & dt <=2013)

Regression_Africa <-lm(AverageTemperature ~ dt, data = Regression_Africa)


Temperature_predicted_temperature <- data.frame(Year = c(2015, 2016, 2020))

predict(Regression_Africa, Temperature_predicted_temperature) %>% round(1)
```

[image]

Comment: If the Year column is `dt` in your data and you created the model with that `dt`, You may need `data.frame(dt = c(2015, 2016, 2020))`

Comment: This is ridiculously simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need to match the names that was used in creation of the model.  In addition, it is better to have a different object name for the `model` other than the original dataset name (in case we want to use the input data again)

```
model <-lm(AverageTemperature ~ dt, data = Regression_Africa)

Temperature_predicted_temperature <- data.frame(dt = c(2015, 2016, 2020))
predict(model, newdata = Temperature_predicted_temperature)
```